# Connect to my OpenVPN server having a proxy on client side

Tags: proxy, openvpn, connect

I have a running OpenVPN server on my house with an OpenWRT router, configured on UDP port 50505. This is actually working with a non-restricted internet connectivity.
Now I have my laptop connected on an enterprise network that has a proxy, they gave me credentials and config for it, but it only allows me to search on the web, and most of them are also restricted.
I'm not able to connect to my VPN Server, but of course if I disconnect from it, disable proxy configuration, and connect to another internet, I can connect.

I don't know what type of proxy do they have on that enterprise network neither I can ask admin to open an exception.

So, is there anyway to reach and connect to my OpenVPN server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most corporate proxies will only permit web traffic (TCP ports 80 and 443) for egress. So unless your admin will allow you to make that exception, which is very unlikely unless it's a small company and/or you know them well, then your only option is to operate your VPN server on one of those ports. Use 443 if you do.

Either run the OpenVPN server on TCP/443 itself, or run it on a high port and have the router port map traffic from 443 to the OpenVPN port.

Comment: Nice! That worked, changed from UDP to TCP-SERVER on 443 and now connected and working.
Thanks!